# Visual Studio 2019 Azure Analysis Services Tabular model deployment issue

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019, azure-analysis-services

I'm trying to deploy my tabular model to Azure Analysis services using Visual Studio 2019 but it is keep showing me error below:

> Cannot deploy metadata. Reason: An error occurred while connecting to the server.

I have installed latest project extension in Visual Studio 19 but no changes. When I am trying to use Visual Studio 2017 deployment works. Can someone please help?

Comment: Not sure but issue seems to be the authentication window, whenever you deploy through VS 17 it opens window to authorize but in VS 19 there is no window. I guess some of those dlls are missing on VS 19 extension.

Comment: Would you like you post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?

Comment: Sure, to get actual fix I think I need raise this up with MSFT team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but issue seems to be the authentication window, whenever you deploy through VS 17 it opens window to authorize but in VS 19 there is no window. I guess some of those  dlls are missing on VS 19 extension.